# Positive bounded operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $A,B$ be positive self-adjoint bounded operators and $\lambda >0$ then I want to show that if

$$A-B \ge 0 $$ that is $\langle x,(A-B)x \rangle \ge 0$ we have that the resolvents (whose existence is clear) satisfy $$(A+\lambda I)^{-1}-(B+\lambda I)^{-1} \le 0,$$ i.e. exactly the opposite relation. Although this is intuitively clear, I got nowhere by applying the definition. I guess there is some trick to flip this inequality over to the other.

Comment: @TrialAndError I think this is something where you immediately know how to do this.

Comment: Can you prove it if $A$ and $B$ commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We immediately have that $B+\lambda\leq A+\lambda$ and that both are invertible. So all we need to show is that if $X\leq Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ invertible, then $Y^{-1}\leq X^{-1}$.

We start with $X\leq Y$. By conjugating with $Y^{-1/2}$ (which is also positive), we get
$$
0\leq Y^{-1}XY^{-1/2}\leq I,
$$
which we can rewrite as 
$$
0\leq (X^{1/2}Y^{-1/2})^*X^{1/2}Y^{-1/2}\leq I.
$$
A positive operator is between $0$ and $I$ precisely when its spectrum is contained in $[0,1]$. And, for invertible $R$, the spectrum of $R^*R$ is the same as that of $RR^*$. Thus
$$
0\leq X^{1/2}Y^{-1/2}(X^{1/2}Y^{-1/2})^*\leq I.
$$
This can be rewritten as 
$$
X^{1/2}Y^{-1}X^{1/2}\leq I.
$$
Conjugating with $X^{-1/2}$ we get
$$
Y^{-1}\leq X^{-1}.
$$

Comment: The $3/2$ in $(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$ should be $3/5$. So the $5/2$ in the final matrix should be $-2/5$. And the $9/10$ in your final matrix should be $2/5-1/2=4/10-5/10=-1/10$. The final matrix is then negative.

Comment: Yes. I took the $1$ from a calculation I made but I evaluated my formulas wrong...

Comment: @MartinArgerami well yes, as you see in my question I am only interested in the case $\lambda >0.$ Although your symbolic argument $X \le Y$ then $Y^{-1} \le X^{-1}$ is also what I used, would you mind giving a rigorous argument based on the definition of $X \ge Y$ if and only if $\langle x,(X-Y) x \rangle \ge 0$?

Comment: I guess I missed that $\lambda>0$. I'll post the argument later, as right now I have to go teach.

Comment: I'm back, and I have edited the answer.

Comment: Much better answer. +1.