Suppose  is an invertible positive operator on V and  is a positive operator on V. Prove that  +  is invertible.
This is from Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition 7C Exercise 7.
The question goes like this:
V is a nonzero finite-dimensional inner product space.
Suppose  is an invertible positive operator on V and  is a positive operator on V. Prove that  +  is invertible.
My current approach:
Because S is invertible and positive, I know there exists an orthonormal basis of V with respect to which S has an diagonal matrix with only positive number on the diagonal. And S^(-1) is also positive.
I know that S + T is also positive, and to show that it is invertible I can try to find an orthonormal basis of V with respect to which S + T has an diagonal matrix with only positive number on the diagonal. But I have trouble constructing one. What am I missing? Or is there other simpler approach?

Hint: Consider $\langle v, (S+T)v\rangle$.

This is actually true for general unital C*-algebras. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578885/if-0-leq-a-leq-b-and-a-is-invertible-then-b-is-invertible .

@Tzimmo Ahh, thank you. I know how to solve it now.

Do you want to self-answer the question, so it doesn't stay open?

I didn't know I can do that. Sure, I can try my best.

(Thanks @Tzimmo for providing the hint.)
For all $v \in V$ and $v\not= 0$, we have
$$ \langle (S+T)v ,  v \rangle =  \langle Sv ,  v \rangle + \langle Tv ,  v \rangle$$
Since $S$ is positive, if $\langle Sv ,  v \rangle = 0,$ $Sv = 0$. Since $S$ is invertible, $ Sv\not=0 $ and thus $\langle Sv ,  v \rangle > 0$.
Since $T$ is positive, $\langle Tv ,  v \rangle \geq 0$
So $ \langle (S+T)v ,  v \rangle > 0$.
This tells us $ null(S+T) = \{0\} $, i.e. $S+T$ is injective. As $S+T$ is an operator, the fact that it is injective implies it is invertible.

The last line is not generally true if we are working in an infinite dimensional space...

Expanding on Tim's previous answer. Once we get that $\operatorname{null}(S+T) = \{0\}$, we then get that
$$\operatorname{range}T^* = (\operatorname{null}T)^\perp = V$$
but since $T*=T$ (since it is positive), we get that $T$ is surjective.
